# Correct order of tasks in each frame for a Physics simulation

Tags: physics, architecture

I'm playing a bit around with 2D physics. I created now some physic blocks which should collide with each other. This works fine "mostly" but sometimes one of the blocks does not react to a collision and i think that's because of my order of tasks done in each frame.

At the moment it looks something like this:

```
function GameFrame(){
    foreach physicObject do
        AddVelocityToPosition();

        DoCollisionStuff();      // Only for this object not to forget!

        AddGravitationToVelocity();
    end

    RedrawScene();
}
```

Is this the correct order of tasks in each frame?

Comment: What do you mean "correct"? If you're talking about physical correctness, then it's not, because in the real world, all those things happen at the same time with infinite precision. Now, for your game, whether that sequence can give an approximation that feels right and fun, is something only you can answer. If one block is not reacting to a collision, then you have to debug the program and see where the collision is being missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple flow, based on experimentation and intuition/common sense:

[image]

This simply means:

- integrate the acceleration and velocity from the current step to recover the predicted, next step position and velocity
- perform collision queries and derive any penalty impulses, forces, friction or whatever
- resolve the collisions in terms of positions (projected iterations to move the bodies iteratively out of conflicting poses)
- feed the penalty response (impulse and force) back to the integrator to use at the next step
- now you can use the output pos and velocities as they're corrected and updated/in synch.